# error: undefined reference to `pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::createActorFromVTKDataSet()'

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

im using ros noetic and pcl1.9.1 on ubuntu 20.04, i added below codes and catkin_make:

```
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr to_show(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>);
    boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer(new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer("viewer"));
    viewer->setBackgroundColor (0, 0, 0);
    viewer->addCoordinateSystem (1.0f);
    pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerCustom<pcl::PointXYZI> h1(to_show, 255, 0, 0);
    viewer->addPointCloud(to_show, h1, "h1");
    while(!viewer->wasStopped()){
        viewer->spinOnce(100);
    }
```

and then occured an error:

```
undefined reference to `pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::createActorFromVTKDataSet(vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataSet> const&, vtkSmartPointer<vtkLODActor>&, bool)'
```

i have already included all c++ source files releated i can find to my code, but it still cant build successfully. Does anybody else has the same issue? Can someone tell me which c++ file the implementation of "createActorFromVTKDataSet()"  locate at?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365559/error:-undefined-reference-to-%60pcl::visualization::pclvisualizer::createactorfromvtkdataset()%27/) by [bgwqy](https://answers.ros.org/users/63312/bgwqy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-11-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My guess is that you're not linking against `pcl_visualization`. Here's a minimal program containing your code, along with a cmake recipe that compiles and links successfully for me under Kinetic on Ubuntu 18.04:

foo.cc:

```
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>

int main(void)
{
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr to_show(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>);
  boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer(new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer("viewer"));
  viewer->setBackgroundColor (0, 0, 0);
  viewer->addCoordinateSystem (1.0f);
  pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerCustom<pcl::PointXYZI> h1(to_show, 255, 0, 0);
  viewer->addPointCloud(to_show, h1, "h1");
  while(!viewer->wasStopped()){
    viewer->spinOnce(100);
  }
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(foo)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  pcl_ros
)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
add_executable(foo foo.cc)
target_link_libraries(foo
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  pcl_visualization
)
```

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/22196/gerkey/) with karma: 1981 on 2020-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Petro](https://answers.ros.org/users/33059/petro/) on 2021-06-10**:
With Ubuntu 20.04 and ROS Noetic Ninjemys, this solved the problem for me when I added "pcl_visaulization" in CMakelists.txt in target_link_libraries